# How to Pass SQL Connection to another php

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying make a very basic android app that can connect to mysql servers and make queries. I have made a first page that requires host, user, name and password. Then I am passing these inputs to a php script (called conn.php) using POST method. If  mysql connection was established a pop up is displayed showing "Success", else it shows the error. Now, I am stuck here. Now I want once I have provided host,username and password and established a connection, I want too use that same connection in another php script which will make queries on the connection.

Here's my conn.php

```
<?php   
    $host=$_POST["host"];
    $user=$_POST["user"];
    $pass=$_POST["pass"];
    $sql=new mysqli($host,$user,$pass);
    if($sql->connect_error)
        echo "Failed: ".$sql->connect_error;
    else{
        echo "Success";
    }
?>
```

Here's My Android Task

```
class ConnectSqlDb extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog waitDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            waitDialog=ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Connecting to MySQLServer","Please wait...",true,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            URL url=null;
            HttpURLConnection connection=null;
            OutputStream os;
            BufferedWriter writer;
            StringBuilder parameter=new StringBuilder();
            try {
                parameter.append(URLEncoder.encode("host", "UTF-8"));
                parameter.append("=");
                parameter.append(URLEncoder.encode(params[1], "UTF-8"));
                parameter.append("&");

                parameter.append(URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8"));
                parameter.append("=");
                parameter.append(URLEncoder.encode(params[2], "UTF-8"));
                parameter.append("&");

                parameter.append(URLEncoder.encode("pass", "UTF-8"));
                parameter.append("=");
                parameter.append(URLEncoder.encode(params[3], "UTF-8"));
            }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                os=connection.getOutputStream();
                writer=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
                writer.write(parameter.toString());
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();

                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String message=br.readLine();
                br.close();
                return message;
            }catch (MalformedURLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            catch ( IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
            waitDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
public void connect(View v){
        String server=phpserver.getText().toString();
        String hostname=host.getText().toString();
        String username=user.getText().toString();
        String password=pass.getText().toString();
        new ConnectSqlDb().execute(server,hostname,username,password);

    }
```

If I am doing it wrong, then what could be another way?

Comment: do you want to make sure that you only have one DB connection? I mean you wanna make sure only one connection establish while running multiple php and multiple queries ???

Comment: yea exactly. I want to use that one connection only, once established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so if you want only one connection, please use singleton class (see singleton pattern).
Define a connection class as follows, 
**DBConnection.php**

```
class DBConnection{
    protected static $db;
    private function __construct() {
        try {
            $host:"myhost";
            $user:"myuser";
            $pass:"mypass";
            self::$db = $sql=new mysqli($host,$user,$pass);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            //..........
        }
    }
    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!self::$db) {
            new DBConnection();
        }
        return self::$db;
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        $db=NULL;
    }
}
```

Note: In you PHP create an Object of this class and pass your values that you get from POST to this class while creating object of this class.
In you PHP file do something like
**conn.php**

```
include "DBConnection.php";
//$host=$_POST["host"];
//$user=$_POST["user"];
//$pass=$_POST["pass"];
//$db = new DBConnection($host,$user,$pass);
$db = new DBConnection();
$connection = $db->getInstance();
```

Comment: I want this connection to be available in another php file where I can make queries, so that i dont need those variables $host, $user, $pass anymore, once the connection is established. Let's say I want to show list of the databases, and later i will be creating tables and using them too. How can i achieve that?

Comment: ok got you, wait you can just make those variable static at php side. let me code

Comment: now see in the class, the connection credential are static, now you can use this same code to get connection instance from that class into any PHP file and list DBs. You can define credentials as class member variable and use using $this keyword.

Comment: Can i use POST method in the php class to get the connection credentials from user end? I want these credentials from user's end.

Comment: no, how can you, you need to call some method from you android to PHP class. So to get using post you need to pass to constructor or any other setter method to the connection class. you define member attribute inside the class and use setter method to set the credentials and then use those member variables to get connection. I need to think about your requirement to get better solution based on your requirement.

Comment: See, I want to make queries on any mysql server. Once user gives his credentials he don't need to give his credentials every time he wants to make a query. He should be able to make any query once he has given correct credentials and connection is established. I need separate files for different types of queries so that i can generate output accordingly, so that i can call different php files according to the query. I cannot achieve this in single php or can I?